# how to convert HashMultiset<String> to Map<String,Integer>

Tags: java, collections, guava

Is there some trick to convert `HashMultiset<String>` to `Map<String,Integer>`, except from iterating all the entries in the `Set`?
Update: The Integer should represent the count of String in the multiset.

Comment: `HashMultiset` is a set. What result exactly do you expect in the map?  What should the keys and values in the map be?

Comment: @Jesper HashMultiset is not a Set (as in a JDK's Set).

Comment: I don't think there is a direct way of doing this. You can perhaps write down your own method, which would be hardly 5-6 lines of code I guess.

Comment: It's not a `java.util.Set`, but it's a set-like datastructure, not a map-like data structure with keys and values, so it's not clear what oshai expects the result to look like.

Comment: @Jesper He probably wants a mapping of unique Strings to their count as map.

Comment: @Rohit is right, seems like getting it as the count of values is pretty general requirement.

Comment: @oshai Even though it is predictable, you should not assume things while posting questions. Add all the details that you think might be required. The question was not understandable to one person itself proves that it is not at all general requirement.

Comment: Can you explain _why_ exactly you want a thing?  IIRC, this isn't in Guava largely because the developers see wanting such a thing as an indication of deeper design issues.

Comment: @LouisWasserman - this is only my opinion, but from api perspective I think it is a reasonable request. `HashMultiset` exposes a way to get count of an item, so I would expect to get an api to get all counts of all items in one call.

Comment: @oshai: Sure: `Multiset.entrySet()` will do that just fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated to java 8, here is what I found as the best answer (based on other answers):

```
public static <E> Map<E, Integer> convert(Multiset<E> multiset) {
    return multiset.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(x->x.getElement(),x->x.getCount()));
}
```

or:

```
public static <E> Map<E, Integer> convert(Multiset<E> multiset) {
    return multiset.entrySet().stream().collect(
        Collectors.toMap(Entry::getElement,Entry::getCount));
}
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use [Maps.asMap](https://guava.dev/releases/23.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Maps.html#asMap-java.util.Set-com.google.common.base.Function-). With lambda expression (Java 8) it will be a one-liner:

```
Maps.asMap(multiset.elementSet(), elem -> multiset.count(elem));
```

In Java 7 and below:

```
final Multiset<String> multiset = HashMultiset.create();
Map<String, Integer> freqMap = Maps.asMap(multiset.elementSet(), 
    new Function<String, Integer>() {
        @Override
        public Integer apply(String elem) {
            return multiset.count(elem);
        }
    });
```

Comment: `elem -> multiset.count(elem)` can be replaced with `multiset::count`.

Answer (score 3):

With [Eclipse Collections](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/) you can use the method [`toMapOfItemToCount`](http://www.eclipse.org/collections/javadoc/10.0.0/org/eclipse/collections/api/bag/Bag.html#toMapOfItemToCount--) on a `Bag` (aka Multiset), which will return a `Map` with a key of the same type in the `Bag` and an `Integer` count.

**Note:** I am a committer for Eclipse collections.

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop through the entries and put the element and count to a map.

```
public class MultisetToMap {
  public static <E> Map<E, Integer> convert(Multiset<E> multiset) {
    Map<E, Integer> map = Maps.newHashMap();
    for (E e : multiset) {
      multiset.count(e);
      map.put(e, multiset.count(e));
    }

    return map;
  }
}
```

Below is the (passing) JUnit test.

```
 @Test
  public void testConvert() {
    HashMultiset<String> hashMultiset = HashMultiset.create();

    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("b");
    hashMultiset.add("c");

    Map<String, Integer> map = MultisetToMap.convert(hashMultiset);
    assertEquals((Integer) 3, map.get("a"));
    assertEquals((Integer) 1, map.get("b"));
    assertEquals((Integer) 1, map.get("c"));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to avoid looping through the entries of the `Multiset`, you can create a  view of it as a Map:

```
public class MultisetMapView<E> implements Map<E, Integer> {
  private Multiset<E> delegate;

  public MultisetMapView(Multiset<E> delegate) {
    this.delegate = delegate;
  }

  public int size() {
    return delegate.size();
  }

  public boolean isEmpty() {
    return delegate.isEmpty();
  }

  public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return delegate.contains(key);
  }

  public boolean containsValue(Object value) {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  public Integer get(Object key) {
    return delegate.count(key);
  }

  public Integer put(E key, Integer value) {
    return delegate.setCount(key, value);
  }

  public Integer remove(Object key) {
    int count = delegate.count(key);
    delegate.remove(key);
    return count;
  }

  public void putAll(Map<? extends E, ? extends Integer> m) {
    for (Entry<? extends E, ? extends Integer> entry : m.entrySet()) {
      delegate.setCount(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
  }

  public void clear() {
    delegate.clear();
  }

  public Set<E> keySet() {
    return delegate.elementSet();
  }

  public Collection<Integer> values() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

  public Set<java.util.Map.Entry<E, Integer>> entrySet() {
    Set<java.util.Map.Entry<E, Integer>> entrySet = Sets.newHashSet();
    for (E e : delegate) {
      delegate.count(e);
      entrySet.add(Maps.immutableEntry(e, delegate.count(e)));
    }

    return entrySet;
  }

}
```

In my implementation, I declined to implement the `containsValue` and `values` methods, as these are not useful in the context. If desired, these could be implemented by looping through the entries and inspecting the `count` of the elements encountered.

And again, you can see this working in this JUnit case:

```
  @Test
  public void testConvert() {
    HashMultiset<String> hashMultiset = HashMultiset.create();

    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("b");
    hashMultiset.add("c");

    Map<String, Integer> map = new MultisetMapView<String>(hashMultiset);
    assertEquals((Integer) 3, map.get("a"));
    assertEquals((Integer) 1, map.get("b"));
    assertEquals((Integer) 1, map.get("c"));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, but only with reflection and it looks very unsafe.

```
    HashMultiset<String> hashMultiset = HashMultiset.create();

    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("a");
    hashMultiset.add("b");
    hashMultiset.add("c");

    System.out.println(hashMultiset);

    Method method = hashMultiset.getClass().getSuperclass().getDeclaredMethod("backingMap");
    method.setAccessible(true);

    Map<String, Integer> map = (Map<String, Integer>) method.invoke(hashMultiset);

    System.out.println(map);
```

Result:

```
[b, c, a x 3]
{b=1, c=1, a=3}
```

Comment: Nope, this won't work.  You'll get back a `Map<String, Count>`, where `Count` is a local class; you can't actually treat the values as `Integer` values.

Comment: ... which javac would in fact have given you a warning about when compiling the above.